# What's the sailing ship equivalent for "Full speed ahead!"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

[image]

It was "full steam ahead" in the time of steamers. One of the last sophisticated sailing ships was the clipper. They were capable of crossing the Atlantic in something like 11 days. Had crews of up to 30 people. Pretty sophisticated stuff.

The storm is over, the rain has slackened. Time to pick up speed. The captain spreads his shoulders and says ... what, exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"***Make all Sail***"

The actions which follow this order can be seen if you Google "let out reefs" to find Ch VI of 'Observations and instruction for ...Royal Navy. 1902'
These actions include letting out the ;reefs' which had  shortened the sail, squaring up the 'yards,' tightening halyards, attaching sails.  The ship could then be described as "under full sail."

> Definition of *in* or *under full sail*  "With all the sails in
>   position or fully spread:" *a galleon in full sail.*   ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-or-under-full-sail))

If they were '*running before the wind*, the wind would be coming from directly behind the boat.

(Spinaker, Gull-Wing or Stud-Sails describe sails set for running before the wind)

> A studding sail, studsail or stunsail (traditionally pronounced
>   stuns'l) is a sail used to increase the sail area of a square rigged
>   vessel or 1950s racing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studding_sail

Antonyms: in irons, three sheets to the wind, bare poles

Comment: Not "carry on"?

Comment: ***"Make full sail."*** was the order in 1902 in the Naval manual. The rest is 'corroborative detail to add verisimilitude.'

Comment: In my ignorance, I wonder because "carry on" originally meant to carry all available sail, I think.

Comment: My ignorance, I think. But all I could find was: 43 f -**Nautical. to proceed under excessive sail for the weather conditions.**  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/carry--on

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to interpret this: ["While the order "Carry On" now mean only to proceed with any duty, it was originally a specific order not to shorten sail, but to carry on all canvas the ship would stand unless stress of bad weather dictated otherwise."](http://www.quarterdeck.org/Terminology/naval_terminology_a.htm#C), but I think it was the order given e.g., to go all out (full steam ahead?) historically. I'll check other sources, but that was given at the two I now have access to.

Comment: Oxford Shorter only has "carry sail" (it does have 'carry out' to loose overboard)  MW on-line has no marine "carry on."

Comment: I still don't know. The OED didn't help. Other sources giving a similar sense for "carry on" didn't provide historical data, just generalities, and some contrary senses. "continue sailing under the same canvas despite the worsening of the wind" (= contrary); "Whenever a good breeze came along, the order to "carry on" would be given. It meant to hoist every bit of canvas the yards could carry."; "officers made the call to ‘carry on’ when the breeze picked up, meaning to hoist all the canvas that the yards could carry to make the most of the available wind." So 'Make all sail' seems safe.

Comment: [The sailor's word-book](https://archive.org/stream/sailorswordbook00smytgoog#page/n173/mode/2up/search/carry+on) (1867) gives "spread all sail" as the meaning of "carry on". The publication date does coincide with the approx. end of the clippers' boom years, for what it's worth.

Comment: That is a brilliant find.  American or English? Is that also Clipper Tea trade?

Comment: It's English, and yes, the use of the clippers as well as their boom in popularity is associated with the demand for more rapid delivery of tea. Their decline is associated with the opening of the Suez Canal. // I'm now thinking that the "carry on" phrase is directly linked to the clippers' characteristics: speed delivered not only by a huge spread of canvas, but the willingness to use the canvas despite adverse conditions.

Comment: **Manual of Seamanship** I (1908 rev.&repr1917) p387 *Sea Terms,* condensed your source from 600 to 5 pages, copying only 2 of the meanings:**Carry on.** -To make all sail at risk when blowing fresh. To proceed.

Comment: @JEL Are you intending to build this into an answer?  If noit I must do some editing.

Comment: @Hugh, I was hoping you would do it: I haven't really examined the *historical* or *inertial* relationships between the term you give in your answer ('make all/full sail', which must be part of the story) and 'carry on'. My original comment ("Not 'carry on'?") was intended as a suggestion for your consideration and remains so.

Comment: "Make all sail" is certainly good enough for children's books. However it's semantic meaning doesn't fit the imaginary scenario... which isn't really that bad considering that the imaginary scenario of "full stop" to "start and go" doesn't exist anyway. **If a clipper had to batten down and furl sails, the captain wanting to get under way would be as likely to yell "Sink my ship" as "Make all sail"**

Comment: The sailor's word-book [https://archive.org/stream/sailorswordbook00smytgoog#page/n173/mode/2up/search/carry+on] is worthy of your time.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler The sailor's word-book [https://archive.org/stream/sailorswordbook00smytgoog#page/n173/mode/2up/search/carry+on] is worthy of your time.

Answer (score 2):

Several other answers cover the extremeness of "All sail" or "Crowd Sail" etc.

As anyone with sailing knowledge can explain there's no single *on switch* for the situation you describe.

The sail to be set would be a matter of precision. The ship's officer on duty would want very specific things, and would give very specific orders.

How strong is the wind? From which direction? Does the ship need to tack and does it have enough momentum to do so?
Next, what sails were reefed or furled during the storm? It would be wrong to assume that a clipper would strip down to bare masts for a storm (a ship without steerageway is the equivalent of trying to balance on a bike without forward momentum).

So an order to **"Shake out", "loose", or "set"** certain sails would be given.

The closest catch phrase of the sort you're describing would be an officer delegating to someone else. **"Prepare to make way"** or **"Get us underway"** might be commands given to a responsible individual who was to use their own judgement regarding what sail was called for by the conditions, then he would give orders for the specifics.

You should be able to find all of the phrases I've used here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms

As well as descriptions of the different types, levels, and categories of sails that a clipper might be equipped with.

Edit: I found a good quote regarding the subject of how much sail would be taken in during a storm. {The answer of course is "exactly as much as was needed"}

[There is no single definition of the characteristics of a clipper ship, but mariner and author Alan Villiers describes them as follows:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper)

To sailors, three things made a ship a clipper. She must be sharp-lined, built for speed. She must be tall-sparred and carry the utmost spread of canvas. And she must use that sail, day and night, fair weather and foul.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***Set all sail!***, ***Crowd sail!*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+all+sail%2Ccrowd+sail&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20all%20sail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrowd%20sail%3B%2Cc0), and ***Crowd on!***

> crowd sail
>
> : (Naut) to carry an extraordinary amount of sail, with a view to
>   accelerate the speed of a vessel; to carry a press of sail. [Webster's
>   Revised Unabridged
>   Dictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/To%20crowd%20sail.html)
>
> In seamanship, to crowd sail, is to carry an extraordinary force of
>   sail, with a view to accelerate the course of a ship, as in chasing or
>   escaping from an enemy; to carry a press of sail [An American Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SqNHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA424&dq=%22crowd+sail%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9gcub67fJAhVM0hoKHbByBgQQ6AEIVzAH#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20sail%22&f=false)
>
> crowd: to put on (sail) in excess of the usual for greater speed
>
> Also, ***put on sail***, [***crack on sail***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22crack+on+sail%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=9TBcVv6rK8iyabOykJAG), ***pack on sail***, ***give
>   hex beans*** (*slang*) [Rogets Int'l
>   Thesaurus](http://tera-3.ul.cs.cmu.edu/NASD/4a7f1db4-5792-415c-be79-266f41eef20a/upgrade-archive-06-14-2007/data/upload-allbooks/disk%203/Jan%20N/ENGLISH/Rogets_International_Thesaurus_III/HTML/00000164.htm)

Answer (score 0):

*The storm is over, the rain has slackened. Time to pick up speed. The captain spreads his shoulders and says ... what, exactly?*

He certainly doesn't say full steam ahead ... he would deploy more sail incrementally, because that is the way it is done: raise the mainsail, raise the foresail, spinnaker out, and so on.  Sailing is a sophisticated art indeed.